# Is there a way to restrict an AngularJS filter to execute only for new values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

**The Goal:**

Restrict AngularJS filter execution to new values only.

**Problem:**

AngularJS filters execute on every $digest cycle regardless of state of input.

**HTML:**

```
<div>{{ ::keyArray | keyToObjectArray }}</div>
```

**Psudo Code:**

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .filter('keyToObjectArray', keyToObjectArray)

function keyToObjectArray() {
    var oldArray = null;
    return function (newArray) {
        // Run only for new inputs
        if (oldArray && angular.equals(newArray, oldArray)) return [];

        var objectArray = [],
            // assign newArray to oldArray
            oldArray = newArray,
            arrayLength = newArray.length,
            position = 0;

        angular.forEach(newArray, function (key) {
            // AJAX request to get object
            getValueObject(key)
            .then(function (objectValue) {
                objectArray.push(objectValue);
            });

            // Update the position
            position = position + 1;

            // Check for completion
            if (position === arrayLength) {
                return objectArray;
            };
        });
    };
};
```

**P.s:** I have already implemented this logic in a directive; I am investigating the possibility of using filters for portability.

Comment: You can use [one time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)  by adding `::` before the expression - making it render only once

Comment: I applied the One-time binding syntax however, the $digest recalculations seem unaffected.

Comment: Can you please include the view part where you applied it in the question?

Comment: Thanks for all your help Alon. I've updated the code.

Comment: I'm not sure filters are intended to be used in this way (read, async requests). The task of transforming an object key to an object seemed simple enough to do in a filter though.

Comment: I've tested One-time binding on a simpler example (One that does not involve an AJAX request) and it works as expected.